# User is being logged out everytime he quits the app

Tags: javascript, facebook, parse-platform, facebook-login, login-script

I am using parse.com for fb login auth.

Looking for solution for this issue,"User is being logged out everytime he quits the app"

JavaScript:

```
    if('sessionToken' in getData)
    {
        var currentSessionToken=getData['sessionToken'];
        Parse.User.become(currentSessionToken).then(function (user) {
            // The current user is now set to user. 
            //mmkay ^_^ wowzaaa
            //update stream ei mmmkay
            toggleLoginUI();
            //   openExploreWithSessionToken(currentSessionToken);
        }, function (error) {
            // The token could not be validated

            toggleLoginUI();
            //openExploreWithSessionToken(undefined);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `localstorage` to store user data. If it exists then do not makee him login again..

Comment: What framework ? iOS or android ? is this phonegap ?

Comment: @RayonDabre : Hey how to use localstorage function? I have been checking with various weblinks too.

Comment: This might help:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage

Comment: Nope it didn't work for me. I updated code. Please look at once

Comment: IssueI happening in both iOS and Android.

Comment: I resolved it . It's was proxy error + syntax error(while writing the parse js coding)